# Labeling an image mask as data for object detection?

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to machine learning but had a question about a labeling method. If I had the following two images:

[image: An object]
[image: Clip of an object]

Is there a way to use the second image as the label for the first one (i.e. anything in white is the object I want to detect)? As I understand it, labels are typically defined by vector points, but in my case, a sort of a raster clipping mask like shown above is much easier for me to generate, as I may have varying shapes of varying complexity. Is there software that can take in an image as the label in this sort of way, or is there no other choice than to turn the raster image into a vector?

If there are any generalizations I'm making then please correct me! I'm not sure if there's an existing tool/method for this out there that I'm completely missing, but any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is called image segmentation.  I suggest reading up on existing methods for image segmentation, and then try applying their approach to your task.  For instance, you might take a look at the DeepLab architecture and train a DeepLab model; there are many others as well.  Labels in image segmentation are normally described by a mask, not by vector points.